# Dual boot - Replace linux distro(Windows 10, Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, arch-linux, windows, dual-boot, manjaro

My laptop is currently running both Windows 10 and Ubuntu with Dual boot.

I've been wanting to replace my Ubuntu with Manjaro(Arch). But I'm afraid it'll hurt the windows 10 partition and I wouldn't be able to obtain access to it again.

Will the new Bootloader from Manajro's installation will let me access the windows 10 partition? What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most important thing not to forget is to backup ([check this out](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/4026181/windows-10-find-my-bitlocker-recovery-key)) your Windows 10 BitLocker recovery key if it is turned on.

You would then proceed with installing Manjaro. Manjaro should automatically detect Windows partition and insert appropriate lines into (assuming) `grub2`. If you were using UEFI the problem shouldn't exist in the first place.

If anything goes wrong, you can always boot to Windows using installation USB/DVD/CD, choose `Repair your computer` -> `Troubleshoot` -> `Command Prompt` and issue the following commands

```
bootrec /FixMbr
bootrec /FixBoot
bootrec /ScanOs
bootrec /RebuildBcd
```

Then boot to Manjaro, mount your Windows 10 partition and run

```
sudo update-grub
```

check [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197868/grub-does-not-detect-windows) for reference.

Comment: First of all, thank you for the fast reply! Should I enable Bitlocker? what does it do?

Comment: BitLocker is a full disk encryption brand for Windows 10 and I believe is only available on Windows 10 Pro. So no, if you don't have it enabled, don't worry about it.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much! When installing Manjaro, I just need to install over the Ubuntu partitions?

Comment: Pretty much, yes, Manjaro has an installer and in the `Partitions` section you would select `Manual partitioning`, delete your current linux and re-create the partition for your Manjaro. For reference https://itsfoss.com/install-manjaro-linux/

Comment: You can also check out my tutorial on this if you have trouble - this is how to do things manually without a smart auto-install program: https://scriptsandoneliners.blogspot.com/2017/06/dual-booting-ubuntu-wwindows-10-easy.html